# Android: How to pass a float Value to mysqlServer?

Tags: android, mysql

I want to store a data of float type into mySqlserver..I tried  namevaluepair for passing the data..Unless NameValuePair What other Options are there for passing Non String Values...

```
Float currentuserrate,serverrate,newrate;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> r = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
newrate = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format((currentuserrate * count + serverrate)
                                    / ++count));
 r.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newrate", newrate));
```

I got error  that using NameValuePair Only String Value can be passed...Plz Help me Out....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameValuePair` takes only String value.You can't add float value to name value pair . you better parse the string value to float ..like

```
$newrate= (float) $_REQUEST['newrate'];
```

in the php file before save to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use wrapper class to Change `Float` to `String` like:

```
r.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newrate", Float.toString(newrate)));
```

You can use any DataType and also JSON String like that way... :)

Happy Coding... ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's normal because `NameValuePair` takes only String values. You better *parse* your `String` to `FLoat` in the **.php** file before adding it into the database.

```
$floatNumber= (float) $stringValue;
```